# Java - Printing commas in a loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, output

I'm running into this problem where if want to loop through an array and print out its contents separated by a comma, it prints out an extra at the end.
I did some searching but, couldn't find an answer that worked for this situation.

Code:

```
public String toString(){

    String hold= "";
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i ++){

        if(array[i] == true){
            hold + = i;
            if(i != array.length-1)
                hold+= ",";
        }
    }
    return hold;
}
```

Comment: Just check if the current iteration is the last one as in: if (i == arr.length - 1) System.out.print(element); else System.out.print(element + ", ");

Comment: for the occasional loop I use a boolean which gets set on the first loop and inserts a comma on every other loop. but iv been writing a code generator recently where this pattern comes up a lot, so i made a class to represent it. internally is maintains and boolean to determine if its 'print' method has been called more than once. only then it outputs the required value (passed in on the constructor).

Answer (score 1):

in Java 8, you don't need this at all anymore:
If its Array of string then following will give you same thing you want to achieve.

```
String joined = String.join(",", name);
```

[how-to-convert-array-to-comma-separated-string](http://javarevisited.blogspot.sg/2016/03/how-to-convert-array-to-comma-separated-string-in-java.html?m=1)

Another way Java 8, would be

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);

    System.out.println(numbers.stream()
        .map(number -> String.valueOf(number))
        .collect(toStringJoiner(", ")));
```

Answer (score 0):

After the loop just check if it ends with a comma

```
for(whatever){
  whatever
}
if(hold.endsWith(","){
  hold = hold.substring(0,hold.length()-1);
}
```

EDIT:

```
String arrayString = Arrays.toString(my_array)
arrayString = arrayString.substring(1,arrayString.length()-1) // gets rid of the '[]'
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm looking for a way to not even generate the comma in the first place

Comment: I added a different way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the last `array[i]` is not `true` so your logic testing for

```
if(i != array.length-1)
```

is not entered into.

But anyway simply replace

```
if(hold.endsWith (","){
  hold = hold.substring (0, hold.length()-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
      public String toString(){
            String hold= "";
            for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i ++){

                if(array[i] == true){
                    if (i != 0) {
                        hold += ",";
                    }
                    hold += i;
                    // if(i != array.length-1) {
                    //   hold+= ",";
                    // }
                }
            }
            return hold;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

it's very easy with Java 8:

```
String[] values={"foo", "bar", "baz"};

public String toString(){
    return Arrays.stream(values).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
}
```

pre-Java 8 I'd go for this verbose way:

```
public String toString(){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Iterator<String> iterator = Arrays.asList(values).iterator();
    if(iterator.hasNext()){
        sb.append(iterator.next());
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            sb.append(", ").append(iterator.next());
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps
(You can grab the logic and integrate with your code)

```
String op = "";
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    op += i != 0 ? ", " + arr[i] : arr[i];
}
```